# How to receive data from Wetrack2 concox GPS device at server?

Tags: c#, gps

what type of socket is used by that device to communicate with the server? how to implement the protocol of that device at server side? I am trying to develop vehicle Tracking application using that device, but I couldn't access that device and couldn't get data from it. So please help me to get data from that device.
It is an image of data flow diagram of that device
[Data flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Cr9.png)